# Weird svg/path animation behaviour in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, svg

When I animate a SVG path using `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`
as described in [this](https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/) article

```
<div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <path d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80"/>
    </svg>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

path {
    stroke-dasharray: 282 282;
    stroke-dashoffset: 282;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;

    &.animate {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

When I add the `animate class the path is animates in all browsers (except Edge). Safari animates the path too, except that its end-state looks a bit weird

[image]

You can see the whole `svg` (the edges in the red circle)

I tried `overflow: hidden` or `z-index` but didn't help. If you resize the window a bit, the square is gone and everything looks right.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7yesrwfv/14/)

Any suggestions how this can be fixed ?

Comment: You mean other than download the webkit source code and fix the bug in it presumably?

Comment: That would be awesome :) No, I hoped for a simple css hack. I can, for example fix it as follows: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yesrwfv/52/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svg` is missing the style for `background-color`. Just put the same `background-color` on `svg` as on `body`:

**CSS:**

```
svg{
  background-color: #CA1; // should be the same as on the body
  ...
}
```

[Here is it working](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/46e5vo7a)

Comment: Wow, that did the trick, not sure if adding the background color makes any sense, but it works, thnx a lot!!